# Node JS Object.asign method do not exist

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm

After a few months I returned to Ubuntu to keep working in a Node JS project what I was developing using Windows and deploying on Ubuntu 16 server.

Now, when I execute `npm start` command, the following error is thown:

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/cmd-list.js:113
>
> module.exports.aliases = Object.assign({}, shorthands, affordances)
>
> TypeError: Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method 'assign'

Its not only my project. I believe its my node installation. When I execute any npm comand, like `npm intall -g juana`, the same errors appears

Comment: I have been install /uninstall nodejs and npm several times and nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regard to this error, the actions unleashed to try to resolve it worsened the situation. In short, I got to install node 8, npm 5, and yarn. All this when I rebooted my PC, then it caused Ubuntu to enter a state of emergency. In the end, I reinstalled the operating system and today I work with Node 6 and npm 3

Answer (score 2):

Only Node.js v4 and above has Object.assign built in.
Either update node to a more recent version, or use a polyfill like [object.assign](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object.assign)

Comment: You can check the version with `node -v` from the command-line. Also try `which node` to confirm where your node lives.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my **mac** (macOS Sierra 10.12.6)

I updated node using brew then I had this *object.assign* error.

The problem occurred because node was not **linked**.

On my mac I simply run the following command to fixed the issue.

> brew link --overwrite node

I guess you need to remove a few symlink before installing the new version on node

Hope it helps.